# Is it possible to consolidate my If statements here?

Tags: if-statement

I am developing an 8x8 grid game. Similar to checkers I guess. Players can move in any direction and jump/take a piece in any direction.

I am individually writing out EVERY single move.. including invalid moves. Is there a way for me to clean this up? I believe there is but I just dont see it at the moment, I cant seem to think up a simpler solution.

Everything works fine, I just am curious if its possible to shorten it.

Heres some of the moves:

```
 //If player attempts to move 2 squares within the same column
              if(checkRow == 2 && checkCol == 0){

                 //Checks if row is OOB. If not, Checks to see if there is a player 2 one position to the right.
                 //If yes checks to see if row - 2 equals the initial player. This avoids methods getting called
                 // When surrounded by multiple pieces.
                 if(fromRow+1 < 8 && boardGame[fromRow+1][fromCol].getPlayer()== 2 && boardGame[toRow-2][toCol].getPlayer() == 1){
                       board[fromRow+1][fromCol] = 0;
                       valid = true;
                       updateTurnCount(); 
                 }
                 //Checks if row is OOB. If not, Checks to see if there is a player 2 one position to the left.
                 else if(fromRow-1 >= 0 && boardGame[fromRow-1][fromCol].getPlayer()== 2 && boardGame[toRow+2][toCol].getPlayer() == 1){
                       board[fromRow-1][fromCol] = 0;
                       valid = true;
                       updateTurnCount(); 
                 }

                 else if(fromRow+1 < 8 && boardGame[fromRow+1][fromCol].getPlayer()== 1 && boardGame[toRow-2][toCol].getPlayer() == 2){
                       board[fromRow+1][fromCol] = 0;
                       valid = true;
                       updateTurnCount(); 
                 }

                 else if(fromRow-1 >= 0 && boardGame[fromRow-1][fromCol].getPlayer()== 1 && boardGame[toRow+2][toCol].getPlayer() == 2){
                       board[fromRow-1][fromCol] = 0;
                       valid = true;
                       updateTurnCount(); 
                 }
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't quite get what your asking here but you can certainly pull most of this logic out into simple statements that will cover all cases.

```
    if ( newRow <0 || newRow >8 ) {
            disallowMove();
            return;
        }

   if ( board[newRow][newCol].player() != board[oldRow][oldCol].player() ){
            disallowMove();
            return;     
   }

    board[newRow][newCol] == somethingElse;
    updateTurnCount();
```

Comment: This pretty much answers what I was asking, I cant seem to figure out the logic for dismembering these awful if statements. So this helps! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

lambdas can shorten considerably the code: for instance, declaring just immediately before the main loop

```
auto from = [boardGame,fromRow,fromCol](int deltaRow, int deltaCol) {
  return boardGame[fromRow+deltaRow][fromCol+deltaCol];
};
auto to = [boardGame,toRow,toCol](int deltaRow, int deltaCol) {
  return boardGame[toRow+deltaRow][toCol+deltaCol];
};
```

the conditions can be written like

```
if(fromRow+1 < 8 && from(+1,0) == 2 && to(-2,0) == 1){...}
```

Further cleanup can follow from factorization of repeated code: the action taken is always the same, and uses the same variables pattern: then the lambda (assuming boardGame etc are member variables) could be

```
auto action = [this](int df_Row, int df_Col, int dt_Row, int dt_Col) {
 int f_row = fromRow+deltaRow, f_col = fromCol+deltaCol;
 int t_row = toRow+dt_Row, t_col = toCol+dt_Col;
 if (f_row < 8 && boardGame[f_row][f_col].getPlayer()== 2 &&
     boardGame[t_row][t_col].getPlayer() == 1){
   boardGame[f_row][f_col] = 0;
   valid = true;
   return true;
 }
 return false;
};
```

and the logic become simpler:

```
if (action(+1,0,-2,0)) updateTurnCount(); 
...
```